File appears in directory but not when I search in windows explorer
So, fun problem:  I'm doing some photo file management, and I came across this, using Windows 11:
I have a file: IMG_2542.HEIC
If I navigate to the file directory using cmd, and issue "dir IMG_2542.HEIC", and Importantly, the date reported by the DIR command is reported as 8/19/2024.  This is not the date the photo was taken, but is the "Last Modified Date" in the file system, and is the date that the photo was downloaded from iCloud.
Now, if I open up Windows Explorer, and I navigate to the same folder (verified by copy/pasting the folder name from the command prompt), If I use the Search field in Explorer to look for hte file name, it does not find the file.
However, if I sort by name, and scroll down through the items, I can verify that the file is indeed there, but the search by name doesn't find it!
Further, in Windows Explorer, in the main explorer window, in "details view"it reports the date as 10/1/2023, which is the date that the photo was actually taken (and that's the date I want to use).
I suspect that windows is keeping some sort of file index to speed up searching and that it has become corrupted somehow.  I'm not sure how to fix it though.  Any suggestions?

is this a typo? ... look for hte file name ... please do no comment ... I'll delete my comment after you read it

I've seen that behavior for many years and always thought of it as normal

What’s the question? You have multiple things working against you. First HEIC is a complicated image codec, which natively, has limited support by Windows. In the past there were extensions on the Windows Store that would handle compatibility. Likewise, iCloud support, is extremely weird on Windows. I have seen images refuse to open while still in the cloud but work perfectly once downloaded. Nothing likely is corrupt.

Open a command window, go to the folder and run attrib *.heic What attributes does the file have?
